# Is it a good idea to use a different gemset for staging and production environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

I have the idea to configure my app to use a different gemset for staging and production. My thought process is that by splitting the environments into separate gemsets, I'd have more freedom down the line when/if I need to update gems/ruby/rails. I'd be able to make that change, and test the whole thing out on staging without disturbing the production app/gemset.

To accomplish this, I would have two files on the server, one in each environment's shared directory, named rvmrc. This contains `rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-production --create` for production and `rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-staging --create` for staging.

I would include a task in the deploy script to link the corresponding `shared/rvmrc` file into the app as `.rvmrc`:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :rvmrc do
    run "rm #{latest_release}/.rvmrc; ln -s #{shared_path}/rvmrc #{latest_release}/.rvmrc"
  end
end

before "bundle:install", "deploy:rvmrc"
```

Is this actually a good idea, or am I over-complicating things?

Comment: Typically your staging is going to be running on a different server than your production, so I am not sure if you get much benefit from using a different gemset? 
Also I am pretty sure 'bundler/capistrano' will install all of the gems to shared/bundle under the install directory, your install directories would need to be different if running staging and production on the same machine, so I think you get gem isolation by default?

Comment: True, separate servers might actually make this part a bit easier for me, but this app's use of staging is so lightweight that I can run both apps on the same server. You're right about the `shared/bundle` directory, too. I hadn't noticed that. I wonder what the 'GEM_PATH' environment variable is, then. I ran a script that just does `puts ENV['GEM_PATH']`, and it reported `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-staging:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global`. Maybe bundler alone uses `GEM_PATH`, but 'bundler/capistrano' uses the `shared/bundle` directory (?).

Comment: i am assuming you have different Gemfiles between production and staging right now? `cd staging_dir; bundle list` and `cd production_dir; bundle list` - now just make sure everything you do uses `bundle exec` when running from either staging or production, rake tasks, boot your server (passenger, unicorn, thin etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[house9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317989/house9) was correct, above, when he said:

> I am pretty sure 'bundler/capistrano' will install all of the
>   gems to shared/bundle under the install directory, your install
>   directories would need to be different if running staging and
>   production on the same machine, so I think you get gem isolation by
>   default?

You can see this in action on your server by running `cd /path/to/staging; bundle list` and `cd /path/to/production; bundle list`. If you have different gems installed in each environment, you'll get a different list from each command.

As [house9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317989/house9) also mentioned, you just need to make sure everything you do uses `bundle exec` when running from either staging or production: rake tasks, boot your server, etc.

Since gem isolation is present by default when using bundler/capistrano, there's no reason to put your environments in separate gemsets.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would want all of the gems you are using in production to be used while developing. I would only split gems that are specific to a certain environment and not needed in the other. In most of my apps I typically only have specific gems required for development only. If you need to split gems, you can simple put them into groups such as:

```
group :development do 
  gem 'development gem'
end

group :production do
  gem 'production gem'
end
```