# How do I configure Capistrano to use a different gemset for staging and production environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, bundler

I have two files on the server, one in each environment's shared directory, named rvmrc. This contains `rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-production --create` for production and `rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-staging --create` for staging. This should allow the app to run under its own gemset, because I've built in a task to the deploy script to link the corresponding `shared/rvmrc` file into the app as `.rvmrc`. That task is displayed below, in my `deploy.rb` example.

I still need to get bundler to use the correct gemset during the deploy, though. I thought I could do this by using `set :rvm_ruby_string, "ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-#{rails_env}"` to dynamically set the `rvm_ruby_string` to the environment's gemset. However, I find that my deploys only use the production gemset - even when doing `cap staging deploy`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004712/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-a-different-gemset-for-staging-and-production-environme) for more information on my thought process for even trying this (and to chime in if you think it's just a bad idea).

What do I need to change to get my deploys to use the correct gemset based on the environment?

In my deploy file, the relevant lines that I have (I've stripped out quite a bit) are:

```
require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "staging"
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-#{rails_env}"
set :rvm_type, :system
set :bundle_without,  [:development]

namespace :deploy do
  task :rvmrc do
    run "rm #{latest_release}/.rvmrc; ln -s #{shared_path}/rvmrc #{latest_release}/.rvmrc"
  end
end

before "bundle:install", "deploy:rvmrc"
```

In my production.rb file, the relevant lines that I have (I've stripped out quite a bit) are:

```
set :branch, "master"
set :rails_env, "production"
```

In my staging.rb file, the relevant lines that I have (I've stripped out quite a bit) are:

```
set :branch, "staging"
set :rails_env, "staging"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the ruby version and gemset when you launch the application. I.e. use [rvm wrappers](https://rvm.io/integration/god/) as it is described for the use with God in the link. No .rvmrc symbolic link juggling needed that way.

I.e., if you're using Unicorn, create a wrapper:

```
rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-production
rvm wrapper ree-1.8.7-2012.02@appname-production ree187prod unicorn
```

That gives you ~.rvm/bin/ree187prod_unicorn. Use it instead of unicorn in your start script. Unicorn will then use the correct ruby version and gemset.